# Internal Server Error 500 on files().list() with Drive REST API

Tags: google-drive-api

**Update:** This issue appears to have been resolved. See the [bug tracker report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760989) for details.

---

I am having some difficulty getting a file listing request through the Drive REST API (v3) accomplished without an 
internal server error (error code 500.) I am trying to use the `name` and `appProperties` keys with a call to
`files().list()` in the search criteria with `name` and `createdTime` for the sort order. (This is "case 1" in 
the code below.) The syntax I am using is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

In an attempt to isolate the problem, I have taken the Google Drive API > REST Android Quickstart project
found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) and made some modifications to 
the `getDataFromApi` method as shown in the code block below.

There are six test cases using various combinations of search criteria and sort order fields. Some queries succeed while
others fail with server code 500 and one times out. These results are consistent on an emulator running Android 7.0
with API 24. My issue originated with an earlier release.

I am most interested in getting a solution to case 1 and offer the other cases as my attempt to figure out what was going wrong. I would appreciate any assistance or ideas on what I might be doing wrong or what else may be happening.

```
         private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            // Get a list of up to 10 files.
            List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

/*          Case 1: Crashes with following error:
             500 Internal Server Error
             {
              "code" : 500,
              "errors" : [ {
              "domain" : "global",
              "message" : "Internal Error",
              "reason" : "internalError"
             }],
              "message" : "Internal Error"
             } */
            String query = "name contains 'Test' and not appProperties has {key='X' and value='Y'}";
            String orderBy = "name, createdTime";

//            Case 2: Succeeds and lists files.
//            Like case 1, but "createdTime is dropped in sort order.
//            String query = "name contains 'Test' and not appProperties has {key='X' and value='Y'}";
//            String orderBy = "name";

//            Case 3: Succeeds and lists files.
//            Like case 1, but appProperties criteria is dropped.
//            String query = "name contains 'Test'";
//            String orderBy = "name, createdTime";

//            Case 4: Times out.
//            Like case 1, but the name criteria is dropped.
//            String query = "not appProperties has {key='X' and value='Y'}";
//            String orderBy = "name, createdTime";

//            Case 5: Errors out like case 1.
//            Like case 4, but the selection query is inverted.
//            String query = "appProperties has {key='X' and value='Y'}";
//            String orderBy = "name, createdTime";

//            Case 6: Succeeds and lists files.
//            Like case 4, but name is dropped in sort order.
//            final String query = "not appProperties has {key='X' and value='Y'}";
//            final String orderBy = "createdTime";

            FileList result = mService.files().list()
                    .setPageSize(10)
                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                    // following was added
                    .setOrderBy(orderBy)
                    .setQ(query)
                    // end added code
                    .execute();
            List<File> files = result.getFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    fileInfo.add(String.format("%s (%s)\n",
                            file.getName(), file.getId()));
                }
            }
            return fileInfo;
        }
```

Comment: Please check the edit on my question and my apology for jumping to conclusions sometimes its not the standard answer.

Comment: The simple answer is often the best answer. I do appreciate you taking the time to respond and doing some of your own investigation.

Comment: Your comment to the other question intrigued me enough to go and play with it.   I am always up for Google bug hunting not many people find legitimate bugs this is an accomplishment.  :)

Comment: Lucky me.....;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Major edit of answer:**

I think you should report this as an bug to Google.  I have been playing with it and I cant get `appProperties` to return as part of a [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) its like the file resource doesn't contain that field so you get an error from the [search](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-shareddrives).  This is true even when I have fields set to * which should return all the fields of a file [resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource).

When you report it send them your examples [apps-api-issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025) link this question as well.   Link your issue request back here and I will see if I can find someone on the Google Drive to ping about it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I am aware of the concept of exponential backoff, but I do not believe that it addresses my issue. My test cases consistently fail and never succeed. If the issue is a transient one, I would expect at least an occasional success. The QuickStart app I used presents a button to the user that executes the file().list() request on demand. If I press that button once, twice or ten times with varying delays, the result is always the same and never varies. This leads me to believe that the problem is not a transient one that exponential backoff can address.

Comment: If you get the 500 error does it work if you try it again.   You simply need to implement exponential backoff.  You haven't shown your code so its going to be hard to help you debug the issue.

Comment: If I get the 500 error, it does not work if I try again (or again and again). The test cases fail every time in the ways that I have documented. As for posting my code, I am using the QuickStart program (with only mods to getDataFromApi method) to isolate and to demonstrate the issue. The QuickStart program (as modified) exactly reflects the problem that I am having and and (I hope) ensures that best practices are followed so we don't fall down a rabbit hole with my particular code. Also see my response to @pinoyyid.

Comment: I would rather it have been a typo in my code, but I will submit this as a defect to Google as you suggest with the appropriate links, etc. 
That will probably happen later today.

Comment: let me know when you do and I will forward it on.  Note this isn't the first bug I have seen in v3 its still newish

Comment: I have submitted the defect report which is issue 5033 at https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5033. If I may, I would also like to inquire about issue 4483 which is a defect with GDAA that I reported last May. Thank you! @DalmTo

Comment: I started it as well see if I can find someone on the team to ping about it if they accept it at least we know it's not us who are doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Exponential backoff only applies if the error is transient. This only happens occasionally, eg. when there is a data centre outage.

Many 500 errors are bugs in GDrive where an invalid (or occasionally, even 
valid) request is being dealt with incorrectly. I suggest you use https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it to ensure that your query string is correctly formed, quoted, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I have used the web interface to test each of the test cases and each case fails, succeeds, or times out just as it does in the test code posted in the original question. Of course, if the query was improperly formatted in the code, I would just have copied over the problem to the web interface, so I am not sure what this new test indicates or where to go from there.

Comment: I have also noticed that there is only a failure when appProperties is referenced in the query string and there are two sort fields. The same query that errors out succeeds if only one sort field is used (same setQ , different setOrderBy). I think that this indicates that the setQ string is correct. To the question put by @DaImTo : when it succeeds it always succeeds and when it fails, it always fails. This behavior is the same in the modified QuickStart app and on the web interface.

Comment: I suspected this might be the case. Because it takes a while for the 500 to be returned, I suspect this is an internal timeout based on the amount of work your query is generating behind the scenes. If so, don't expect a quick fix. My suggestion would be to modify your app to run with a single sort field and then post process the results into the desired order.

Comment: That may be, but I think that Google, who can return 560,867 responses to any query I type in within 0.65 seconds, can look at my handful of files and tell me what's what within a reasonable amount of time. My suspicion is that this is a run-of-the-mill defect that they can fix quickly. In the meantime, I will make use of the work-around you suggest.

Comment: You'd think so, but the Google Drive infrastructure is significantly more complex than you might expect. I tried your query using both the v2 and v3 APIs, and get the same result. This suggests that the problem is in the infrastructure tier, not the API tier. The fact that you only have a handful of files, makes the workaround I suggested easier to implement, so I would go with that way forward and if your bug is ever fixed, you can treat it as a nice bonus.