# Bug in Google Drive ? Spreadsheet with real-time document embedded gets Corrupt

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-realtime-api

I have an application that was working stable for 6 months until Jan 17.
Some change must have happened at Google as files started to be corrupt after a while.

The application uses google drive spreadsheet v4 API and Google Real-time api agains the same file. I think it must be the combination of the two that causes the problem. I can do some read/write operations before it happens, but after some time I get "Internal Error" and the file is permanently corrupt after that.

The simple call :

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId: resp.id,
  range: 'A1:F',
  majorDimension: 'ROWS'
})
```

Results in

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
   "status": "INTERNAL"
 } 
}
```

If I try to access the same file as a regular spreadsheet i also get an error message:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iPe2W0NnDPlMahdhHA_rifjqDP61H_gsXel6Qhf_Gbk/edit

Has anyone experienced the same? I assume any bug in my application should under no circumstances result in a corrupt document ?

Comment: You might encounter [`Internal Error`](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/d-zwp_CLdvg) when you are over your storage quota on Google Docs. You can verify this by going to `http://docs.google.com`, clicking the "Upload" button on the left hand side, and looking at the amount of storage you have left. You may also check this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487456/). If you think this is a bug, you may file a [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=823909) regarding this.

Comment: Thanks - I have verified that this is not a Quota problem and reported it as a bug to Google. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66893058